# Редирект соединения на другой сервер без потери ip клиента

Tags: linux, redirect, iptables

Сервера находятся на разных хостингах. Есть сервер, который редиректит, и, который принимает редиректы. Редирект идёт через iptables. Как сделать редирект соединения на другой сервер без потери ip клиента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой ответ - никак.

На самом деле можно, только пакет должен вернуться тем же путем. Для этого:

1. Строим туннель между серверами если сервеа в разных локальных сетях
2. маршрутизация:

   2.а. Указываем второму серверу маршрут по умолчанию через этот туннель

   2.б. Добавляем вторую таблицу маршрутизации и размечаем соединения. трафик этих соединений маршрутизируем в туннель.
3. На первом сервере будет только DNAT правило, за счёт правильной маршрутизации всё дойдет так. SNAT или  MASQUERADE не должны применяться.